# Изменение цвета фона в Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Подскажите, как в unity 3d сделать так чтобы фон игры был одного цвета но разных тонов, сверху темного тока, а снизу светлого ( как на изображении). Пробовал менять камеру на `Solid Color` но он делает весь фон одного тона
[image]

Comment: Вы можете взять вообще любую картинку и поставить на задний план как спрайт (SpriteRenderer), а "сверху темный, снизу светлый" называется градиент

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте в фотошопе градиент от чёрного до белого. Сделайте объект из этого спрайта и меняйте его цвет через SpriteRenderer.color.